# Invalid key in ModelState when validating IValidatableObject in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

## Code

My viewModel:

```cs
public class SearchViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    // ...some properties...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("My custom object-level error");
    }
}
```

My Controller action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(SearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);

    return Content("OK");
}
```

My view:

```html
<form asp-action="Search" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    <!-- the rest of the form -->
</form>
```

## Problem

Inside the Controller action, `ModelState` has an entry with a key `"viewModel"`, instead of `""` (empty string).
Because of that the validation summary div in the View does not render anything.

From my little investigation, the problem is present only on **ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview 1**, but not on **ASP.NET Core 2.0**.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I created an [issue on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7503).